# Why is entropy a state function if the integral of it over a cycle is non-zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I'm quite confused, If it's a state function it is dependent on the properties of state, after we loop a cycle, we return to the same point and hence evaluating entropy at that state and subtracting with original entropy at start, it should total to zero. However the Clausius inequality states that it's less than or equal to zero.. does this mean that entropy is not a state function for irreversible cyclic processes?

Comment: How does the Claudius inquatity day it is non-zero?  Who says this?

Comment: I fixed the wording but I am going off what is said here on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausius_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clausius inequality, applied to the working fluid for an irreversible cycle, states that $$\Delta S=0>\int{\frac{\delta Q}{T_B}}$$where $T_B$ is the temperature at the boundary (interface) between the working fluid and its surroundings (typically reservoirs) and $\delta Q$ is the incremental heat flow across this boundary during the irreversible cycle.  So, what's the problem?  $\Delta S = 0$.  You didn't think that that integral was the entropy change, did you?  That is the entropy change only if the process is reversible.

Comment: wait what..?  so, what is the definition of entropy?  if not $$ dS = \frac{dQ}{T}$$

Comment: Oh, and by the way, if it is a reversible change, shouldn't the temperature at boundary be same temperature at every point? if so, why did you mention that point specifically?

Comment: Yes, for a reversible change, that is correct.  But, for an irreversible change, the system temperature may not be uniform.

Comment: So, what is the explicit expression for entropy actually? if it is not dS=dQ/T

Comment: To get the entropy change for an irreversible process, you need to find the value of that integral for any alternate reversible process between the same two end states.  So you need to devise (i.e., dream up) an alternate reversible process between the same two end states.

Comment: @ChetMiller Is it valid to say the inequality applies because more entropy is transferred out of the system than into the system for an irreversible cycle owing to the fact that for an irreversible cycle the entropy transferred to the surroundings must equal the entropy transferred to the system plus the entropy generated within the system.

Comment: @Bob D I wouldn't express it in exactly those words, but, yes, this is correct.

Comment: @ChetMiller For my future use purposes, which particular words that I used may be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

The Clausius inequality states that over *any* thermodynamic cycle
$$\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T} \le 0$$
where $\delta Q$ is the heat absorbed at temperature $T$; note that the entropy does not come in to play here. Between two equilibrium states, say $\mathcal {A}_ 1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$, we also have  $$\int_{\mathcal{A}_1}^{\mathcal{A}_2} \frac{\delta Q}{T} \le S(\mathcal{A}_2) - S(\mathcal{A}_1)$$ where $S(\mathcal{A})$ is the system entropy in state $\mathcal{A}$.

In both cases you have the equality sign hold for a reversible process and the inequality sign for an irreversible process.
When the loop is completed you are back to the same state, $\mathcal{A}_1=\mathcal{A}_2$, hence the entropy change is $0$ irrespective of the process being reversible or not.

There is some controversy if and how one should define entropy during an irreversible process but that has no relevance to the answer as it is stated to start from equilibrium at the beginning and to stop in equilibrium at the end of the process.

---

A process to which a body can or cannot be subjected is *not* arbitrary. In thermodynamics it is limited by a so-called constitutive inequality, in other words, the material of which the body is made and its configuration puts a limit on the ability it can absorb heat where "absorbed heat" here is the difference of the internal energy *of* the body and the external work done *on* the body. This "entropy function" is the limiting characteristic in the sense that if you denote by $\dot Q$ the rate at which the body absorbs then $\dot Q \le T\dot S$ at every instant and every rate.

If you wish, you can rewrite this in the following form: $$\mathcal {\dot E} \le T\dot S +\mathcal{\dot W}$$
where $\dot {\mathcal W}$ is the rate of working (i.e., "power") done on the body whose internal energy is $\mathcal E$. This inequality shows how fast you can increase the internal energy by working on the body. There is no physical process by which one may increase the internal energy *faster* than is allowed by this so-called Clausius-Duhem inequality.

I have written the Clausius-Duhem inequality in the form of rates that it is true no matter how fast the process is but you can equally well write it as $d\mathcal E \le TdS+\delta \mathcal W$ since both internal energy and entropy are state functions, hence the $d$, but since work is not we need the $\delta$ to emphasize it.

Comment: I'm so confused if only the reversible integral is entropy what is the excess terms which terms comes for irreversible path...?

Comment: I'm still quite confused